# Slide an element without animation upon page load in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a div on my page, that I can collapse (using jQuery) using a button, and I want the  to be collapsed by default (when the page loads). I did this using window.onload :

```
window.onload=function(){$("#upgradeInfoCollapse").slideToggle("fast");}
```

But, when the page loads, the collapse animation is executed. I want the  to collapse, without the animation (I want it to be collapsed when the page loads).

I tried using `. slide` instead of `.slideToggle` , but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

HTML :

```
<div id="upgradeInfoCollapse" class="collapsed">
<h3>Upgrade 1</h3>
<p>Cost : $3.5k<br>Capacity Upgrade : 5000</p>
<h3>Upgrade 2</h3>
<p>Cost : $5k<br>Capacity Upgrade : 7000</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size:105%">You cannot sell upgrades!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use inline styles like this. That paragraph could be, for example, `<p class="warning">` then have a separate .css file with `p.warning { ... }`. If you're seriously a _N00b_ try to learn good habits while you're learning the tech.  
Also, since you're using jQuery, use `$(document).ready(function() { /* do stuff */ });` instead of `window.onload`. In a separate .js file.

Comment: I do have a seperate .CSS file that is 200 lines long. The paragraph was styled this way just because I was testing stuff. Also yes, I do have a seperate .js file for all my JavaScript. What is the benefit of using $(document).ready instead of window.onload?

Comment: First, `.ready()` fires when the DOM is built, even though there may be images etc. still downloading, so it doesn't wait as long to get started. Second, `window.onload=someFunction` _replaces_ any onload handler that may have been added, so you can't build up a number of things to happen when load completes. Maybe a 3rd party library initializes itself _onload_ (bad move on their part) and you prevent it from initializing by replacing their onload handler. Using multiple `.ready()` functions adds them all on so multiple things can happen when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks! Any way of doing     .ready() in pure JS (no jQuery) ?

Comment: Yes, with the `DOMContentLoaded` event. See [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Example) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the div in a collapsed position using CSS with the "display: none" code. Then, you have the div expand on click using the toggle javascript method.

Here is an example I found:

[try it](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I could display the div as none, because I thought that it has to be displayed in order for it to be shown/collapsed again later. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @td ... a good answer on SO should be self-contained; that is, if your _"try it"_ link breaks the answer still makes sense. Having a little sample code of your own in the answer would help. Links to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (or similar) that you control are better than links to 3rd parties that can rearrange their pages and break your link. You can even make your own runnable examples with [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) directly in your answer.

Comment: Good call, @StephenP. I'll be sure to add that in the future. The answer below mine from BravoZulu has the code snippets I would have shown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `collapsed` class to your div. That way, it will already start as collapsed, without using JQuery.

CSS:

```
.collapsed {
    display: none;
}
```

After that, you can toggle your div with:

```
$("#upgradeInfoCollapse").toggle()
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding the class to the div doesn't help. Here is the HTML for that div :

<div id="upgradeInfoCollapse" class="collapsed">
 <h3>Upgrade 1</h3>
 <p>Cost : $3.5k<br>Capacity Upgrade : 5000</p>
 <h3>Upgrade 2</h3>
 <p>Cost : $5k<br>Capacity Upgrade : 7000</p>
 <p style="color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size:105%">You cannot sell upgrades!</p>
 </div>

Comment: Guess I didn't see your CSS code? Or did you add it later? Anyways it works now. Thanks!